# Form with 2 fields in the same line in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, forms, grid, label, sapui5

I am creating a form in sapui5 and I have to put several fields, so that it does not become too long I wanted to put several fields together horizontally but I do not see any way to do it, that is to say, I have seen two input together horizontally but not with a descriptive text for each one. What I want is what is shown in the following image

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssu4b.png)

This is what I have:

```
<f:Form id="FormChange354" editable="true">
                    <f:layout>
                        <f:ResponsiveGridLayout labelSpanXL="3" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" labelSpanS="12" adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="4" emptySpanL="4"
                            emptySpanM="4" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1" columnsL="1" columnsM="1" singleContainerFullSize="false"/>
                    </f:layout>
                    <f:formContainers>
                            <f:FormContainer>
                                <f:formElements>
                                    <f:FormElement label="{i18n>Nombre}">
                                        <f:fields>
                                            <Input value="{SupplierName}" id="name"/>
                                        </f:fields>
                                    </f:FormElement>
                                    <f:FormElement label="{i18n>Apellido1}">
                                        <f:fields>
                                            <Input value="{Apellido1}"/>
                                        </f:fields>
                                    </f:FormElement>
                                    <f:FormElement label="{i18n>Apellido2}">
                                        <f:fields>
                                            <Input value="{Apellido2}"/>
                                        </f:fields>
                                    </f:FormElement>
                                </f:formElements>
                            </f:FormContainer>
                    </f:formContainers>
                </f:Form>
```

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleForm_Column_twoGroups234. Each `<core:Title>` creates a group (if you want that). `columnsM/L/XL` is your friend

Comment: But if I don't want a title? I tried but i don't like with titles. Are there anything more? I thought grid but I don't know. Thank you for your answer @Marc

Comment: Sry, I was posting a link to a SimpleForm. You are using a regular Form. There are plenty of samples here to create two columns in a regular Form: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.form.Form

If you don't want a title just remove the property. To create more columns you probably just have to create more FormContainers inside your form.